# How to run a function repeatedly with a fixed delay using Python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have a function `f()`that I want to run from time to time, let's say each 10 seconds. My goal is to run it indefinitely, only being killed by a interrupt. I looked into the `sched` module, but couldn't find how to run the function repeatedly ad infinitum. Maybe a `while True` loop?

Comment: I think you just need the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module with `time.sleep(10)` in a `while True` loop, unless your requirement is more complicated than you have explained in the question. Note that this will give a 10 second pause after each function call, but will not take into account how long the function itself takes to execute.

Comment: I would you a loop, with sleep function, e.g. `from time import sleep
sleep(0.1) # Time in seconds`

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

while True:
    f()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Try it!